# Expected full URL but got a child path, use ref instead

Tags: javascript, firebase, error-handling

This is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49536475/firebase-reffromurl-is-not-a-function) thread, but it's a new problem I encountered. I am trying to add an image to a table cell in HTML, and I'm using Firebase Storage in combination with Firebase Database for this. The idea is to get the image from a `gs://xxxxxxxx` path in the database and use it in the js, but I get this error in the console:

> Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in `refFromURL` at index 0: Expected full URL but got a child path, use ref instead."

So it seems that the `url_ul` path is not working. If, for example, I introduce the 'gs://xxxxxxxx' instead of `url_ul`, it works like a charm. And if I read the value `url_ul` as a text, I get that path. However, it doesn't work if I have that variable in `refFromURL('url_ul')`

I have the following js code for this:

```js
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Test");
var storage = firebase.storage();

rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {
      var headline = snap.child("headline").val();
      var url_ul = snap.child("imageUrl").val();

      var storageRef = storage.refFromURL('url_ul').then(function(url) {
        var test = url;
        document.querySelector('img').src = test;
      }).catch(function(error) {});

      $("#table_body").append("<tr><td>" + headline + "</td><td><img src='test' alt='' border=3 height=100 width=100></td></tr>");});
```

where the database looks like this:

[image]

So there is a gs://xxxxx path, which, according to Firebase documentation, should work fine:

> // Create a reference from a Google Cloud Storage URI
>   var gsReference = storage.refFromURL('gs://bucket/images/stars.jpg')

Any idea what is wrong here?

---

To make things more clear:

This line works perfectly fine:

```
var storageRef = storage.refFromURL("gs://nameofapp.appspot.com/armonii_culturale.png").getDownloadURL().then(function(url) ...
```

But this one doesn't

```
var storageRef = storage.refFromURL("url_ul").getDownloadURL().then(function(url) ...
```

And it's strange because "url_ul" should contain the same value.

Comment: `'url_ul'` is a string instead of the variable you want. Just use `url_ul`, no quotes because it's a variable.

Comment: Thank you so much! That actually solved it. But now all the images are loaded over the same cell tab, instead of filling the cells. Is there a way to solve that? And if you write an answer, I would vote it as the best answer.

Comment: That's really a separate question. I'd recommend you make another question for it. That way, when other developers have similar problems in the future, they will have an easier time searching for the solution.

Comment: I wrote a new thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49543111/images-from-firebase-storage-crowd-in-the-same-html-table-cell